# How to make Google Chrome recognize this extension as a new extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I had a chrome extension built for me and it helps me publish to my wordpress with ease. The problem is that I have a few websites that I would like to use the same extension for which involves nothing more than changing the URL in the extension's settings.

**The real question**

Assuming I made 3 copies of the same extension, what changes must be implemented in each one to make Google Chrome recognize it as a different extension? Right now, if I change certain attributes in the manifest, Chrome will still recognize it as the original extension and will want to replace the extension I already have installed.

I hope this makes sense. Apparently *someone* didn't understand what I was talking about so I broke it down. Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: I think it's something like the name and the private key it's signed with

Comment: I figured out the issue. Guess you were right. There is an API key in there, one for developers and for some reason when all three of them had the same key, it would recognize it as one extension. So my follow-up question is, how do I register for my own API key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only guessing, but I would think that it would be the `name` field found in the `manifest.json` file. In theory, if you are managing your own `.crx` file (for packaged extensions), I guess Chrome could use the name of that file as well. And finally, if you are signing your extension and making it available through the market, the cryptographic signature could be used as well (the `.pem` being created when you package your extension).

So no real answer, but I believe it must be one of these three (name in manifest, name of crx file or cryptographic signature). If you test it and figure out, be sure to share!

Comment: I figured out the issue. There is an API key in there, one for developers and for some reason when all three of them had the same key, it would recognize it as one extension. So my follow-up question is, how do I register for my own API key?

Comment: Open up chrome://extensions, make sure "developer mode" is active, and try to "pack extension". If my memory serves me right, it will create a key for you if you leave it blank.

Comment: yeah, it's just a RSA keypair that anyone can generate for an extension. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/packaging.html